# Modify object value in array inside map

Tags: javascript, loops, object, updates

Trying to modify object value in array on condition on some arrays the override does not work, here is my snippet

```
const removeAction = (target, array, name) => {
        let mutation = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
        mutation.map( obj => {
            if(obj.value === target.value) {
                console.log(obj)
                obj.checked = false
            } 

            return obj
        })

        console.log(mutation)
        removeCallback(mutation, name)
    }
```

and I get back the original object in array. How do I debug this issue?

Comment: `.map` returns a modified **copy** of the array. You never use that value

Comment: "*I get back the original object in array.*" - where? What does not work? How do you call this, what is `removeCallback`? Are you passing a `target` that is not part of the `array`? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
const modifiedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)).map(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Map always returns new instance of array. So either assign that mutated map to some variable or loop over and mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the mapped objects with destructuring the object and an updated property.

```
const
    removeAction = (target, array, name) => {
        removeCallback(array.map(obj => ({
            ...obj,
            checked: obj.value === target.value ? false : obj.checked
        })), name)
    };
```

Comment: Thanks I tried as well I get the same result, It has something to do with Initial array passed to the function